# Declare variable only once BEFORE render in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to grab the height of a div in React using `useRef` and assign it to a variable, `defaultHeight`.

```
const jselectRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null)

let defaultHeight: number | undefined
console.log(defaultHeight) // returns undefined

useEffect(() => {
    if (jselectRef.current !== null) {
        defaultHeight = jselectRef.current.offsetParent?.clientHeight
        console.log(defaultHeight) // returns the height of the div (40)
    }
}, [])

console.log(defaultHeight) // returns undefined, even after first page render
```

Since `useEffect` runs *after* the page is rendered, I need to declare the `defaultHeight` variable outside of it, but assign it to the ref inside of it.
However, when I declare the variable outside of `useEffect`, then the variable gets reset to *undefined* every time my component re-renders.

Is there a way to tell React to only declare the variable
`let defaultHeight: number | undefined`
once, **before** page load? Then once `useEffect` sets the variable based on the ref, leave it alone?
`useEffect` doesn't work here, because then the first load will be `undefined`, which triggers TypeScript.

I don't think `useMemo` would apply here since we are just declaring the variable, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: why don't you use state or another ref?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava state works, but using state for a variable that is only set once and then never changes seems redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use another ref. (This is largely what refs are for--variables that persist across renders--so this seems like the best option to me.)

```js
const defaultHeight = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
 // ...
 defaultHeight.current = 123;
})
```

Or use state, but note that this could trigger a re-render, which you may not want.

```js
const [defaultHeight, setDefaultHeight] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
   // ...
   setDefaultHeight(123);
}, [])
```

Or you could move it outside the component altogether, but as [Giorgi Moniava rightly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804583/declare-variable-only-once-before-render-in-react/73804660?noredirect=1#comment130322061_73804660) in a comment below, this approach **will cause interference if the component is used in multiple places--they'll all update the same variable--and is therefore not recommended**. Leaving this option here just to note why you *shouldn't* do it this way.

```js
let defaultHeight;

function MyComponent () {
  useEffect(() => {
    // ...
    defaultHeight = 123;
  });
}
```

Comment: IMHO outside component in general is bad practice, if you have multiple components I think all will refer to that variable

Comment: I don't disagree. I'm assuming the component is the only thing exported from the file/module so it's not going to pollute anything beyond the file.

Comment: Even if that's the only thing in that file (besides that variable). If someone imports that component from multiple places, the components will refer to same instance of that variable IMHO

Comment: Oh. Right. Right. Yeah. If it's used more than once they'll interfere with each other. Right. I misunderstood, but I see what you mean now.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: Neat, didn't know refs could be used for that!
I had tried using state (which works and persists across renders) but as you mentioned, it triggers an unnecessary render. And since the value never changes once it's properly defined, it seemed redundant.